# bundle.js cannot be found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am building an app using react with browserHistory of react/router 2.0, and lite-server. The Router code is following

```
const appRouter = (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={LandingPage}/>
            <Route path="/posts" component={Posts}/>
            <Route path="/posts/:postId" component={Post}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>
);
```

The error is X GET http://localhost:3000/posts/lib/bundle.js

This error only happen when the url is http://localhost:3000/posts/somePostId and after refreshing the page or

The lib/bundle.js file suppose to load from root '/', but it is trying to load from '/posts/'.

I just switched from hashHistory to browserHistory, and the error is happened after switching.

Comment: can you add your javascript tag where you are calling bundle.js

Comment: Please add your `package.json` file too

Comment: Most likely, you're including it as `./lib/bundle.js`. You'll have to use absolute path, as in `/lib/bundle.js`, i.e. without the `.` at the beginning.

Comment: I believe the problem is about browserHistory. There is no error after change from browserHistory to hashHistory.

Comment: The solution is here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50275901/react-routing-path-not-working-bundle-not-found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50275901/react-routing-path-not-working-bundle-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a route `<Route path="/posts/:postId" component={Post}/>`,

which match the path of your bundle.js: `http://localhost:3000/posts/lib/bundle.js`, please try to move your js files into another folder or use another path.