# React routing, path not working, bundle not found

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

The following route works great and displays the AdministratePage component:

```
 <Route path="/admin" component={AdministratePage} />
```

However this route:

```
 <Route path="/admin/all" component={AdministratePage} />
```

...results in the following error:

> http://localhost:8080/admin/bundle.js 404 (Not Found)

Where do I go wrong? Am I not allowed to use any path?

I'm using react-router-dom 4.1.2.

My webpack.config.js :

```
  output: {
        path: path.resolve('dist'),
        filename: '/bundle.js'
    },
```

My index.html:

```
   <div id="app"></div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Slash looks useless here

```
filename: '/bundle.js'
```

Also try to define publicPath

```
output: {
  filename: 'bundle.js',
  path: path.resolve('dist'),
  publicPath: '/',
},
```

https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/

Comment: Thanks! That works. Question, do you have any idea where this bundle.js is stored on the filesystem? Can't find it in my client folder...

Comment: Should be in dist after build. When you are using webpack server(dev mode) - you will not see it

Answer (score 7):

Another way of solving this problem is to add the following tag to your `index.html` page:

```html
<base href="/">
```

Comment: This one saved my day. I did not want to change webpack. Thank for this alternative solution!

Comment: good Lord. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please explain what's going on, and how this fixes the problem? It worked, but I'd like to also know why

Answer (score 0):

React-router v4 now allows you to use regexes to match params

```
<Route path="/admin/all | /admin" component={AdministratePage} />
```

It uses path-to-regexp

[path-to-regexp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp)

Comment: No luck. I'm under the impression that the answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37962559/using-webpack-with-react-router-bundle-js-not-found But I don't reference the bundle in my index.html