# Can't load JS bundle on route in React

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a React app, using webpack. I have added React Router 3 and when trying to visit a route in my app, I get a 404 on the .JS files when on anything but the initial route.

My application is also using a basename as I must prepend the application path.

**Routes**

```
import React from 'react'
import Loadable from 'react-loadable'
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, IndexRedirect } from 'react-router'
import App from './components/App'

const AsyncRoute = loader =>
  Loadable({
    loader,
    loading: () => <h3>Loading...</h3>,
    delay: 300,
  })

const LandingPage = AsyncRoute(() => import(/* webpackPrefetch: true, webpackChunkName: "landingPage" */ './containers/LandingPage'))

export default ({ history }) => (
  <Router history={history}>
    <Route path="/:tenant" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={LandingPage} />
      <Route path="foo" component={LandingPage} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
)
```

**Index**

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { useRouterHistory } from 'react-router'
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux'
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory'

import store from './store'
import Router from './routes'

const historyConfig = { basename: '/content-manager' }
const browserHistory = useRouterHistory(createBrowserHistory)(historyConfig)
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store)

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Fragment>
      <Router history={history} />
    </Fragment>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

**Webpack.dev**

```
const PORT = process.env.SERVER_PORT || 3000
const HOST = process.env.SERVER_HOST || '127.0.0.1'

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  mode: 'development',
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
    publicPath: '',
  },
  devServer: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: process.env.PORT || 3200,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: false,
    open: true,
    proxy: {
      '/api/**': {
        target: `http://${HOST}:${PORT}`,
        pathRewrite: { '^/api': '' },
        secure: false,
        logLevel: 'debug',
      },
    },
  },
}
```

**Webpack.common**

```
const commonPaths = require('../common-paths');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
  context: commonPaths.appPath,
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './index.jsx'],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(jsx?)$/, exclude: /node_modules/, use: ['babel-loader'] },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          chunks: 'initial',
          test: 'vendor',
          name: 'vendor',
          enforce: true,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Web App',
      template: commonPaths.projectRoot + '/public/index.html',
      inject: 'body',
    }),
    new CompressionPlugin({
      algorithm: 'gzip',
      test: /\.js$|\.css$/,
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.8,
      deleteOriginalAssets: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'prod',
    }),
    new Dotenv(),
  ],
};
```

If I visit `http://app.local/content-manager/foo` in the browser, the landing page will load.

If I then trying and navigate to `http://app.local/content-manager/foo/edit` the application does not load and I see the following in the console

```
GET http://app.local/content-manager/foo/main.fdb34ff55bc02a8cd347.js 404 (Not Found)
edit:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://app.local/content-manager/foo/main.fdb34ff55bc02a8cd347.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

I believe on the initial route, it is trying to find the js bundle at `http://app.local/content-manager` but then when I move to a sub route it is looking in `http://app.local/content-manager/foo`

Comment: Can you restart the server once and see if its the same

Comment: It is the same if I restart the dev server :(

Comment: The solution is here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50275901/react-routing-path-not-working-bundle-not-found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50275901/react-routing-path-not-working-bundle-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

So I have added

```
<base href="/content-manager/" />
```

into my index.html and now it seems to work....