# Why i can't access route in react after refresh after build create on server?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have to add routes for front end as "/How-it-works" and for admin end as "Admin/Route-name", with following code it works fine and i can access with refresh as well locally but when i create build and access on server it generate an error.

```
    <Router history={history} >
        <Switch>
            <FrontEndLayoutWrapper exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <FrontEndLayoutWrapper exact path="/How-it-works" component={HowItWorks} />
            <AdminAuthRoute    exact  path="/Admin" component={AdminIndex} />
            <PrivateRouteAdmin exact path="/Admin/Companies" component={CompanyList} />
            <PrivateRouteAdmin exact path="/Admin/Festivals" component={FestivalList} />
            <PrivateRouteAdmin exact path="/Admin/Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />              
        </Switch>
    </Router>
```

In webpack.config.js i have output property in module.exports as this:

```
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'bundle'),
      filename: 'index_bundle.js',
      publicPath: '/',
   }
```

and i have already set historyApiFallback to true in module.exports as well.

```
devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: true
}
```

Error:

> GET http://localhost:8080/Admin/index_bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
>   (Not Found)

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React routing, path not working, bundle not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50275901/react-routing-path-not-working-bundle-not-found)

Comment: This is something to do on serverside routing. on apache or nginx or at least express that boots up react app.

Comment: You might have to set contentBase in the webpack devServer configuration https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-contentbase