# Only main page loads after React App Build, other pages returns your file couldn't be accessed error (ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm a beginner in React JS and is trying to do basic routing in the app.
The **app serves fine on development using npm start server** and **serve -s build**.
[image]

- The build/index.html created in production using '**npm run build**', served blank page initially.
- On adding **"homepage" : "."**, it served the components in the main page (here index.js) alone.
  [image]
- The links in the navbar (home.js, about.js and contact.js) are not loading
  error message - **your file couldn't be accessed - ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND**
- On clicking home link:
  [image]
- On clicking about link:

[image]

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>React Router Tutorial</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root" class="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';
import About from './About';
import Contact from './Contact';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/contact">Contact</Link></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
      <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
    </Routes>  
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**home.js**

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home Page</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**about.js**

```
export default function About() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>About Page</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**contact.js**

```
export default function Contact() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Contact Page</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

build folder contains the files - index.html, asset-manifest.json and static/js directory with main.js, main.js.LICENCE.txt and main.js.map files as below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Routes choose just one Route and render it. Routes render Main component first cuz its path is "/". In your code, when you click one of Links in nav. You can't go to the link cuz it's not rendered which means Browser can't access the component you want. If you wanna move page, you should useNavigate not Link. If my answer helped you, pls select my answer :D have a nice day.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I tried  the suggestions, it's working fine on localhost but build/index.html after npm run build yields blank page even with "homepage" : "." in package.json.

Comment: @lizbeth I guess It might be what you find.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50275901/react-routing-path-not-working-bundle-not-found

Comment: I have updated the question with more details. Pls see if it helps.

Comment: Routes choose just one Route and render it. Routes render <Main /> component first cuz its path is "/". In your code, when you click one of Links in nav. You can't go to the link cuz it's not rendered which means Browser can't access the component you want. If you wanna move page, you should useNavigate not Link. If my answer helped you, pls select my answer :D have a nice day.

Comment: Sorry I'm here when I have little time in a day. You should follow tutorial here! https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial

Comment: I'll be thnakful if you select my answer :D Enjoy coding!